# I would like to 'draw' a basic 2D mesh of any shape using my mouse

Tags: modeling, mesh, 2d

I would like to 'draw' a basic 2D mesh of any shape using my mouse. I've read advice on using grease pencil, but if I use grease pencil and convert to a mesh it seems to have lots of different properties and the mesh doesn't behave normally at all. I feel like this would be a straightforward feature that a lot of people would want as it would save a lot of time, so maybe i'm missing something?

For example I want to create the outline of a beer bottle (or any shape using a reference photo), and have as simple a mesh as possible? Instead of creating a basic object and manipulating it.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that this approach doesn't really save too much time, since handdrawn shapes must be cleaned... manually. But I concede that it's probably suitable if you're just making a sketch!

Anyway: you can definitely do it using grease pencil! What is the problem you're experiencing?

This is a possible workflow. Precondition: use Blender 2.80 or newer.

- *Add > Grease Pencil > Blank*
- Get into an orthographic view (e.g. *Front Ortho*)
- Entrer "Draw Mode", draw; then go back to "Object Mode"
- Right click on your object > *Convert to Bezier Curve*
- In the *Outliner*, hide the grease pencil object and select the newly created Bezier curve.

  In my version, I have a little bug whereas the Bezier is not immediately visible. Hop in and out of Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to make it visible

  [image]
- Your curve has probably *too many* handles. To reduce them, enter "Edit Mode", select all the handles (<kbd>A</kbd>), then do *Right Click > Decimate Curve*. In the box that appears, select a suitable value.

  [image]
- To avoid your mesh to have still *too many* handles, go in the *Curve* settings and change *Resolution Preview U* to 2 or 3
- *Right Click > Convert to Mesh*
- You've got your mesh! You can use it as any other mesh. For instance, you can use the Screw modifier

  [image]

Comment: riiiight ok, that's great thanks. Yes if I follow your instruction exactly then it works perfectly. I think i was basically converting the grease pencil directly to a mesh. Which would appear to give me what i wanted, but whenever i would go into edit mode it wouldn't give me all the 'mesh' options, it would just give me the same options as grease pencil. Couln't figure it out! great thanks :) I'm not to worried about clean up right now, planning to use this for some 3D printing reasons, so basically just looking to draw a 2D shape then give it some depth so i can print it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for this in Edit Mode called *Poly Build*. It is basically a quicker way of creating, connecting, moving, and deleting geometry by "drawing." This seems to fit your use case.

[Documentary of the Poly Build tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/poly_build.html)

> The Poly Build tool uses many built operators in an interactive way to add, delete, or move geometry. This is extremely useful for retopology.